# How to query with like 'KD%' in ruby on rails ActiveRecord with has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a has_many relation in ruby on rails ActiveRecord, I need to query with like 'FD%', couldn't find any example on that.

Here is what I need:

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :client, -> {where(name: like 'FD%')}
```

And it keep telling me that like is not allowed. Not sure if anyone has any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this:

```
has_many :client, -> {where("clients.name like 'FD%'")}
```

the `clients.` is optional, bu if your Test model has name column you will get an error.